# SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 SP4 - Where is the official package repository?

Tags: linux, url, repository, suse, yast

I'd like to install `nano` on a virtual machine installed with SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 SP4. There are no package repositories defined in YaST. What repo URL should I use? I can't find any on the web.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hmm. "SUSE Linux Enterprise Server and openSUSE use zypper for package management and YaST for system administration." from [Package and System Management Tools for SUSE Linux Enterprise Server and openSUSE](https://www.suse.com/communities/blog/package-and-system-management-tools-for-suse-linux-enterprise-server-and-opensuse/)

Comment: [SDB:Zypper usage](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB%3aZypper_usage): "This article is about how to use Zypper, the command line package manager using the Libzypp library for installing, updating and removing packages as well as for managing repositories. It is especially useful for accomplishing remote software management tasks or managing software from shell scripts. "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a repository for this version, but it is still possible to download an ISO.

The name of the ISO is `SLES-10-SP4-DVD-i386-GM-DVD1.iso` for the i386 version,
or `SLES-10-SP4-DVD-x86_64-GM-DVD1.iso` for the x86_64 version.

Here are a couple of download links
that I found using Google :

- [SLES-10-SP4-DVD-i386-GM-DVD1.iso](ftp://151.155.5.212/partner/product/Misc/SLES-10-SP4-DVD-i386-GM-DVD1.iso)
- [SLES-10-SP4-DVD-x86_64-GM-DVD1.iso](ftp://151.155.5.212/partner/product/Misc/SLES-10-SP4-DVD-x86_64-GM-DVD1.iso)

Comment: It's sad that these files cannot be downloaded from http://www.suse.com anymore... Thanks for the links. I needed the 64-bit version, so I downloaded the second one. I found the MD5 hash of the iso on the web, so I could test it and it was OK. Unfortunately, I could not find `nano`, only `vi` and `joe` were available in the iso.

Comment: Nano can be [installed from scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/nano.html).

Comment: I tried it but `make` fails with `nano.h:93:20: error: curses.h: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Perhaps nano-2.0.6 [worked once](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/nano-2-0-6-suse-linux-10-0-enterprise-592205/).

Comment: I solved it... Using a "version bisection method", I quickly found that the latest rpm which could be installed without problems was 2.1.7. So I did `wget http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.1/RPMS/nano-2.1.7-1.x86_64.rpm` and then `sudo rpm -i nano-2.1.7-1.x86_64.rpm`.

Comment: Link for SLES 10 SP2 i386: ftp://ftp.okhysing.is/suse/SLES-10-SP2-DVD-i386-GM-DVD1.iso